# Is it possible in Photoshop to cut rectangular slices of the same dimension from a "n" number o photos in a different position each one?

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying the technique called Time Slice which is basically this: you have "n" number of photos and cut a slice from every one of them, in the order they were shot and following a patron in the position of every slice (I explain the process). I'd spent hours making the slices manually. I tried some scripts, but so far they work in a different ways. This is the process that I do every time I do the slicing manually.

1. I have the photos in C:\Users\Isabel\Pictures\Tobecut with a name that is numerical, so the first photo that I took its called 0, and the others 1, 2, 3, 4 ..... to "n"
2. Determine if the slices will be horizontal or vertical:

**If horizontal, then:**

2.1 Divide the height of the photo (every photos of the same project have the same size, but it is variable from one project to other) for the number "n"+1 of photos. This give me the height dimension of the rectangular selection for the slice.

2.2 The width of the photo it is the width of the rectangular selection for the slice

2.3 Having the rectangular selection that will be the slice, now I have to position that selection for each photo. I use the bottom transform selection to manually write the (x,y) coordinates of the center of the slice. I obtain those coordinates using this formula:
x=(The height of the rectangular slice/2)+(Number of the photo that will be sliced*The height of the rectangular slice)
y= The width of the photo/2

2.4 Once I have the slice positioned in photo, slice the selection, deleting the rest, that is outside the rectangular selection

2.5 Save the rectangular slice as tiff in C:\Users\Isabel\Pictures\Slices

2.6 Repeat this process with the rest of the "n" photos and stop when finish

**Or if the slices will be vertical**

2.1 Divide the width of the photo for the number "n"+1 of photos. This give me the height dimension of the rectangular selection for the slice.

2.2 The height of the photo it is the width of the rectangular selection for the slice

2.3 Having the rectangular selection that will be the slice, now I have to position that selection for each photo. I use the bottom transform selection to manually write the (x,y) coordinates of the center of the slice. I obtain those coordinates using this formula:
x= The height of the photo/2
y= The height of the rectangular slice/2)+(Number of the photo that will be sliced*The height of the rectangular slice)

2.4 Once I have the slice positioned in photo, slice the selection, deleting the rest, that is outside the rectangular selection

2.5 Save the rectangular slice as tiff in C:\Users\Isabel\Pictures\Slices

2.6 Repeat this process with the rest of the "n" photos and stop when finish

I know that is to rude to ask but I can't help myself, I reading JavaScript for children but I cannot make it through the basics. Could someone help me to write the script?

Comment: It is not rude at all to ask. That is the only way you can learn when you are really stuck. Unfortunately, SO is not the right place to ask. We usually deal with specific programming questions about code that has already been written. Perhaps some of the other users can point you to a good tutorial, but in the meantime I have a feeling your question will just be closed.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: Im sorry, my bad, i already post this question in that place, tank you Mad Physicist and Morales Batovski

Comment: How do you decide if the slices will be horizontal or vertical? How big is N usually? Do you have any links to websites explaining the technique?